# SQL Query Design with Two separate tables? MySQL PHP PDO Performance

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo, database-performance

I'm wondering how to design my SQL query when I have two separate tables, but should work together...

`likes` table

**Columns** - idlikes, idusers, like_what

---

`user_follow` table

**Columns** - idfollow, follower, following

---

What is the best way to design a query for optimization/performance? Can queries be combined? Or am I supposed to separate each query like this:

```
$iduser = 1 //I am user 1 in database.

$get = $db -> prepare("SELECT * FROM user_follow WHERE follower = ?")
$get -> execute(array($iduser));
while($row = $get->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
     $following = $row['following']; // get id of user that i'm following

     $likes = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM likes WHERE idusers = ?");
     $likes->execute(array($following));
     // do what I need to..

}
```

---

UPDATE

```
$following = $dbh->prepare("SELECT L.* FROM likes L JOIN user_follow F on L.iduser = F.iduser_following WHERE F.iduser_follower = ?");
$following->execute(array($iduser));

while($row_following = $following->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
  $id1 = $row_following['L.iduser'];
  echo $id1;
}
```

Comment: Take a look at joins: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/join.html

Comment: By the way, PDO is just an API, a set of functions. It has nothing to do with database performance. Just for your info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do it in one query

```
SELECT L.*
FROM likes L
JOIN user_follow F ON L.idusers = F.following
WHERE F.follower = ?
```

A note on naming:  In sql each row contains one value thus column names are typically singular.  Thus `likes.idusers` would typically be `likes.iduser`

I would also make it clear if it is a FK on iduser, so in the user_follow table I would name `follower` as `iduser_follower` and `following` as `isuser_following`

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Also, I'm trying to put my query together, but nothing shows up. Please check if I'm doing it right?